# ListObject with Name defined by a variable or an Array

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I am trying to create a series of NEW ListObjects with their Name defined by a variable or an array value.

```
TblNameArray = Array("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4",)

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(R1, C1), Cells(R2, C2)), , xlYes).Name = TblNameArray(w)
```

I get two new Tables with the correct names and then it stops with no error.
I would prefer using a Variable, but i have not figured out how to use a variable in that location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need a loop going thru TblNameArray and need some changing R1,C1,R2,C2 on each iteration.

Comment: Can you please paste enough code into your question so that people can replicate your problem.  At the moment there is no way to replicate what is happening, or even **guess** as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's hard to see what, exactly, you are trying to do. However, the code below does work and perhaps that will help you find your way.

```
Private Sub InsertTables()

    Dim TblNameArray As Variant
    Dim TblRangeArray As Variant
    Dim w As Integer

    TblNameArray = Array("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4")
    TblRangeArray = Array("A2:G8", "A11:G15", "A21:G25", "A31:G35")

    With Activesheet
        For w = 0 To UBound(TblNameArray)
            .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                             Source:=Range(TblRangeArray(w)), _
                             XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes).Name = TblNameArray(w)
        Next w
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListTables()

    Dim Tbl As ListObject

    For Each Tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        Debug.Print Tbl.Name
    Next Tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!!! - This code worked well for what i am doing. I am new to ListObjects [Source].   If you can point me to a good explanation of using [Source] if would be most appreciative.

Comment: MSDN is the most authoritative source of information on VBA, and often the best. Try this link for an example, but googling the name of the object you are interested in (in this case "VBA ListObject") may lead you to other explanations which are sometimes easier to understand. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobjects-add-method-excel